# Ideas for splitting a string into character groups

Tags: c#, linq, parsing

In order to test a generic Markov Chain class, I would like to split some text into character groups. To start with, just vowel and consonant groups and eventually add punctuation and perhaps others.

I'm looking for ideas on building a function that will do the following:

```
in: "hello", out: { "h", "e", "ll", "o" }
in: "world", out: { "w", "o", "rld" }
in: "Hello world!", out: { "h", "e", "ll", "o", " ", "w", "o", "rld", "!" }
```

I realize I can iterate through the character array with a for loop and build each group by comparing the value, but I'm wondering if there is an easier and/or faster method.

I am interested in any answers that meet **any** of the following:

- easy to implement and read, like a simple linq query for example,
- demonstrate a technique that is useful in other scenarios,
- good performance,
- rely on some uncommon feature (related to second point I guess).

I'm looking specifically for a C# solution, but I would be interested in solutions in other languages as long as I can translate them (i.e. they don't rely on a language specific feature).

Comment: Why the downvote? What can I do to improve my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example text, with vowels and consonant groups:

```
Regex.Split("Hello World","(?<=[aeiou])(?=[^aeiou])|(?<=[^aeiou])(?=[aeiou])|(?<= )")
```

However, your example input and output also shows splits on two other character types (punctuation - !) and space, so you might as well just go ahead and write yourself an `IEnumerable` extension method.

```
void Main()
{
    "Hello World!".it().Dump();
}
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<char[]> it(this string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            yield break;
        
        var z = CharacterClass(s[0]);
        var chars = new List<char>();
        foreach(var c in s)
        {
            var c2=CharacterClass(c);
            if (c2!=z)
            {
                yield return chars.ToArray();
                chars.Clear();
                z=c2;
            }
            chars.Add(c);
        }
        yield return chars.ToArray();
    }
    
    public static int CharacterClass(char c)
    {
        // 1 = vowel
        // 2 = space characters
        // 3 = punctuation
        // 0 = everything else
        var classes = new Dictionary<char,int> {{'a',1},{'e',1},{'i',1},{'o',1},{'u',1},{' ',2},{'!',3}};
        if (classes.Keys.Contains(c))
        {
            return classes[c];
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on what the regex is doing? My regex-fu is a little low and I would be interested in trying to expand this to cover the other character classes. I had planned to make it an extension, but it's what goes inside that I'm trying to get ideas on. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: The regex looks to see if (the prior character is a vowel, and the next is not a vowel) OR (the prior character is not a vowel and this one is) OR it's a space.  The IEnumerable is much more friendly.  Just write your own CharacterClass method to return what class a passed in character is, and the `it` extension method will group them for you.

Comment: Answer accepted. That's similar to what I have, but I was using "aeiuo".IndexOf(c) != -1  and/or "aeiuo".Contains(c) as my test.  Besides the possible performance difference, is there any reason to prefer your dictionary based check?

Comment: Not really.  I just did that way so that it could return multiple types of values easily (return an int instead of a bool).  It could easily just be a 65536 byte array (and it would be even faster) that returns a byte.  Depends on how many of these you are going to be converting and what memory you are willing to use to get that extra performance.  Although, 64k is usually trivial on all devices these days.